# PHP: redirect using "header ()" not working

Tags: php, http

code:
sql.php

```
<?php
$uid = trim($_POST['uid']);
$pass= trim($_POST['pass']);
$type= trim($_POST['type']);
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","akash");
if (!$link) 
                 die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
if(!mysql_select_db("fsproj",$link))        
die("Can't Select database");
if ($type == 0 ) 
$query = "select uid from admin where uid = \"$uid\" AND password = \"$pass\"";
else
$query = "select username from user where uid = $uid AND pass = $pass";
$result = mysql_query("$query",$link);                        
$num_r=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        header("Location : codepage.php");
exit();
?>
```

code: login.html

```
<html>
<form action="sql.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" target=result>
Enter UID

<textarea name="uid" id="uid" rows="1" cols="40"> 

</textarea><br>
Password

<textarea name="pass" id="pass" rows="1" cols="40"> 

</textarea><br>
Type

<textarea name="type" id="type" rows="1" cols="40"> 

</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

All the files are in the same root directory, submitting the userid and password through login.html to sql.php should redirect to the file codepage.php (I havent added the login check yet, so should succeed for any values of username as password)

But when I try to do so, All I get is a blank page.

If I add an output statement after the header call, I see the output of that statement

Essentially, `header("Location : codepage.php")` had no effect

The header function does work in some other pages on the same site

Comment: are you sure that the execution does not stop at one of the die() statements??

Comment: @pinglocalhost Yes, I added an echo("Hello") statement between the header() and exit() calls. "Hello" appeared on my browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use curly brackets. Your code is broken the way it is.</strike> Also, it's `header('Location: codepage.php')`, not `header('Location : codepage.php')`. Notice the extra space you've added.

**REMOVED**

Comment: The braces arent needed, the code is in progress and for a single statement after an if condition the braces are not required. the last else condition has only the $query in it, rest of the code after it has to be executed regardless of the $type condition

Comment: My mistake. However, I'd strongly recommend you always use them.

Comment: Yes, I'll add them before the actual submission. Just find them irritating when changing parts of the code

Answer (score 2):

The `header('Location: address')` should contain the ENTIRE url, not just the file.

This means the protocol, domain and alternatively folders and files.

```
header('Location: http://wwww.google.com');
```

Docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Here are the w3 specifications on the Location header at point 14.30 (search for '14.30 Location')

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

To qoute the w3:

> The field value consists of a single absolute URI.

As noted in the comments, there may not be any whitespace before or after the the colon (:).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Surprisingly it was working in another page without giving the full path...

Comment: The issue isn't that he didn't use the full path it's that he had a space between `Location` and `:`.

Comment: The most often problem isn't an uncomplete URL but spaces before ":" or no space after ":" of the "Location" header ;)

Comment: Removing the space worked as well! (how can I get PHP to show such errors in the log?)

Comment: It really isn't a php error but your mistake in interpreting the http protocol, php doesn't check syntax for that since it's fairly  flexible on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Your codes are vulnerable to `Sql Injection`. Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to filter. Like:

```
 $pass= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass']));
```

And make sure that you have corrent address to codepage.php. Try

```
header('Location: /codepage.php'); //OR
header('Location: http://site.com/to/codepage.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

please used header("Location: codepage.php");

the problem is the space between Location and :
it's working for me, hope it will work for u